# count number of simple paths between two nodes in a given graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I want to find the number of simple paths from A to B in the following undirected graph, where each node can be visited only once. I wrote a code and found the answer is 55. Just wonder whether there is a general math counting algorithm to solve this kind of problem. For example, if we add a few more diagonal edges, can a general algorithm be used to solve it on paper? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Counting the number of simple paths between two nodes is $\textsf{#P}$-complete [1], which is strong evidence of intractability. That is, it is unlikely that an algorithm or "nice" combinatorial formula can be effectively used to give a solution in general.

[1] https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397579900446